# Slick slider - arrows invisible until it's in viewport

Tags: css, slick.js

I have been facing this problem multiple times with slick carousel

You can't see the arrows until scroll into slider's "viewport". It looks kind of z-index problem, but it's definitely not

Video of this problem 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/33fu5btk5c3wqfn/Video%2002-02-2018%2C%2010%2038%2008.mp4?dl=0

This might also happen when slides are changing with transformX (not fade as this case). Arrows disappear when slider is changing slides and get's back as soon as transform is done

I'm not attaching full html+js+css code. Hopefully there are some people who have faced this before and know what I'm talking about, as it's fairly common

```
.slick-arrow{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -webkit-calc(55% - 25px);
  top: calc(55% - 25px);
  height: 50px;
  left: 65px;
}
```

Could it be something to do with `will-change`, `transform` or other fancy things that might help and force buttons to be on top of slider?

The rest of css is just regular bundle from slick.js repo (latest version)
`.slick-slider` have `touch-action: pan-y` and `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent` which also confuse me a bit

P.S. Site link http://mice.surge.sh/homepage.html (.reviews__slider section)
Most likelly you wan't see the bug on desktop devices. It was noticed on iOS devices

Comment: so the problem is carousel's arrows are hidden unless you place your finger inside the element? hmm..

Answer (score 0):

What I see is different from what's there in the video.

[image]

To solve this, you need to add `left: auto` to `#reviews .reviews__slider .slick-arrow:last-child{ }`

Please let me know if this helps.